# How to call input value in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a only one question

I begin learn a flutter in yesterday.

How to get a Textfield value ?

I tried call a TextEditingController anybody in a class.
But It's not working to.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final userId = TextEditingController();
  final userPass = TextEditingController();

  ...TextInputField(),
          PasswordInput(),
          LoginButton()
```

}

```
void loginAct() async {
  var data = {
    "user_id": userId,   //undefined
    "user_pass": userPass,  //undefined
  };



class TextInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputField({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
      child: Container(
        height: size.height * 0.08,
        width: size.width * 0.8,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[500],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        ),
        child: TextField(
          controller: userId,  <=== (The getter 'userId' isn't defined for the class 'TextInputField')
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            prefixIcon: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
              child: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.user,
                size: 28,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
            ),
            hintText: 'id',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how to resolve that?

Comment: you want to login and pass your data to API it is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this on your code

```
class TextInputField  extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextInputField({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final userIdController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
       return Container(
          child: TextField(
         controller: userId, 
         onpressed:  () {loginAct(password:passwordController.text,userName:userIdController. 
          text)})
   );
 
}
```

your login function

```
   void loginAct({String password, String userName}) async {
   var data = {
  "user_id": password,  
  "user_pass": userName, 
  }
```

Comment: So.. How do I call from loginAct() when I initialized within the class?

i tried call variable from the each class 
`TextInputField { final userId ... }`
`PasswordInput { final userPass ...}`
`LoginButton { onPressed : loginAct() }`


`void loginAct() {`
 ` var data = {`
   `"user_id" : userId.text   //undefined userId`
   `... 
}
}`

Comment: wait i will update the answer .text is access where the controller is define

Comment: I consolidated the separated widget classes into one and tried and succeeded. thank you so much bro!!

Answer (score 3):

if flutter you can get text field value by different methods

1. by text editing controller

add this on top

```
final userNameController = TextEditingController();
final passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

then on text field

```
TextField(
  controller: userNameController,
);

 TextField(
  controller: passwordController,
);
```

and on function pass the value as you like

```
onPressed: () => loginAct(userNameController.text,passwordController.text),
```

in this case you need to specify what is initial value through controller

for Second Question

```
http.get(Uri.https('https://swapi.co', 'api/people'));
```

or

```
http.get(Uri.parse('https://swapi.co/api/people'));
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching.
But I failed resolve that. 
I tried call a final userId = TextEditingController() in  top controller

but It is occur defined class error

So.. I added full code in question. thank you

Comment: i added another answer for you , you get that error is due to your using different widget class , text editing controllers are generally uses on its on state full or stateless widget